# USB problems with systemd-udev ends up consuming all resources

Tags: drivers, usb, udev

I've been having this problem from which none of the related answers have solved my issue. I got this `systemd-udevd` instance which keeps growing its resources consumption until the laptop just freezes.

The issue seems to be related with a HP device with following PCI ID `03f0:0c51`, however I haven't been able to figure out which kind of device [this is](https://devicehunt.com/search/type/usb/vendor/03F0/device/0C51). `dmesg` is spammed with the folowing data over and over again:

```
$ dmesg
[  667.720371] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 50 using xhci_hcd
[  667.883752] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0c51
[  667.883754] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  667.883754] usb 1-2: Product: H380
[  667.883755] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HP
[  667.883756] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 003580023000167
[  667.903096] cdc_mbim 1-2:1.0: bind() failure
[  667.903604] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  667.904039] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[  667.904510] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[  667.908866] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 50
[  668.328363] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 51 using xhci_hcd
[  668.487939] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0c51
[  668.487940] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  668.487941] usb 1-2: Product: H380
[  668.487942] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HP
[  668.487943] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 003580023000167
[  668.507062] cdc_mbim 1-2:1.0: bind() failure
[  668.507535] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  668.508086] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[  668.508527] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[  668.513128] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 51
```

`udevadm` also shows the device to be added and removed constantly:

```
$ udevadm monitor --udev
UDEV  [910.996048] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [911.002337] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [911.002462] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [911.002572] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [911.008984] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [911.009123] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [911.009234] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.5 (usb)
UDEV  [911.009347] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.7 (usb)
UDEV  [911.010646] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.5 (usb)
UDEV  [911.010771] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.6 (usb)
UDEV  [911.010874] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.7 (usb)
UDEV  [911.014092] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
UDEV  [911.016825] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [911.017042] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.8 (usb)
UDEV  [911.017148] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.4/tty/ttyACM1 (tty)
```

curiously the device `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2` does not seems to exist, since the comand `udevadm info --query=all /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2` just returns an error. `lsusb` fares no better, and the device just pops up in the result from time to time but offers no real information:

```
$ lsusb | ag 0c51
Bus 001 Device 047: ID 03f0:0c51 Hewlett-Packard
```

`journalctl` offers the following output:

```
Feb 20 16:39:11 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[4499]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeare
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[2584]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeare
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[1]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeared t
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0c51
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: Product: H380
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HP
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 003580023000167
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_mbim 1-2:1.0: bind() failure
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop mtp-probe[11190]: checking bus 1, device 75: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop mtp-probe[11190]: bus: 1, device: 75 was not an MTP device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 75
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[4499]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeare
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[1]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeared t
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[1]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeared t
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop systemd[2584]: dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device: Dev dev-serial-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:14.0.device appeare
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0c51
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: Product: H380
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HP
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 003580023000167
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_mbim 1-2:1.0: bind() failure
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
Feb 20 16:39:12 MyLaptop kernel: usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 76
```

finally, I tried to check `systemd-udev` itself:

```
$ sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd -D
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:13
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' returned non-zero
MODE 0664 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:41
PROGRAM 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 1 27' /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules:1923
starting 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 1 27'
'mtp-probe /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 1 27'(out) '0'
Process 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 1 27' succeeded.
RUN '/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev %p' /lib/udev/rules.d/85-tlp.rules:10
handling device node '/dev/bus/usb/001/026', devnum=c189:25, mode=0664, uid=0, gid=0
can not stat() node '/dev/bus/usb/001/026' (No such file or directory)
created db file '/run/udev/data/c189:25' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'
starting '/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'
seq 33375 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33376 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33377 queued, 'remove' 'tty'
could not create device: Invalid argument
could not create device: Invalid argument
seq 33380 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33381 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33382 queued, 'remove' 'tty'
could not create device: Invalid argument
could not create device: Invalid argument
seq 33385 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33386 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33387 queued, 'remove' 'tty'
could not create device: Invalid argument
could not create device: Invalid argument
seq 33390 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33391 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
seq 33392 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
could not create device: Invalid argument
seq 33394 queued, 'remove' 'usb'
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) 'cat: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/busnum': No such file or directory'
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) 'cat: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/devnum''
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) ': No such file or directory'
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) 'cat: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/idVendor': No such file or directory'
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) 'cat: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/power/level': No such file or directory'
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) '/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev: 127: /lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev: '
'/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2'(err) 'cannot create /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/power/level: Directory nonexistent'
Process '/lib/udev/tlp-usb-udev /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2' succeeded.
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dd0ed0
seq 33315 processed
passed 295 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 295 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 294 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 310 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
seq 33318 running
seq 33321 running
passed 294 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 310 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 294 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 310 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0seq 33328 running

passed 296 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
seq 33317 running
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'seq 33331 runningvalue '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
seq 33326 running
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15

value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.6'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.5'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
seq 33333 runningRUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5

RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5

created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.6' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.6'
Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic02isc02ip00in06'
RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.1' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1'
Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip02in01'
created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.5' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.5'Inserted 'cdc_acm'

Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip00in05'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
No module matches 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip02in01'
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dc7960
seq 33328 processed
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'No module matches 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip00in05'

passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dd0ed0
seq 33317 processed
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfc080
seq 33326 processed
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
passed 214 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
passed 298 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
passed 298 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
seq 33329 running
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9
seq 33346 running
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
seq 33336 running
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'

GROUP 20 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:26
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.8'value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'

IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:7
created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.2' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2'
Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic02isc02ip01in02'
Inserted 'cdc_acm'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules:8
RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfc080unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.6/tty/ttyACM2'

seq 33336 processed
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
seq 33316 running
created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.8' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.8'
Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01icFFisc01ip00in08'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'
IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
No module matches 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01icFFisc01ip00in08'
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dc7960
seq 33346 processed
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfbc90
seq 33333 processed
passed 299 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'

unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.7'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'HP'RUN 'kmod load $env{MODALIAS}' /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules:5

IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:15
created db file '/run/udev/data/+usb:1-2:1.7' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.7'
Execute 'load' 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip00in07'
No module matches 'usb:v03F0p0C51d1729dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Aisc00ip00in07'
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dbd440
seq 33331 processed
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules:9

passed 298 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.3'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
unable to access usb_interface device of '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0'
IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' returned non-zero
passed device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfc470
seq 33318 processed
passed 214 byte device to netlink monitor 0x556d95dfe9e0
```

Basically the same message over and over again.

I tried to add the following rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c51", OPTIONS+="ignore_device", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
SUBSYSTEM="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c51", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

But they don't seem to work either. Any idea of what I can do next?

Comment: I have the same problem on HP laptop, did you found a way to resolve the issue?

I also have different problem with this laptop, USB devices are only working when I plugin usb devices before I boot laptop. If I plugin devices later, they are detected by lsusb, dmesg and usb-devices but aren't working. Do you have similar issue with yours laptop? Maybe idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0c51 spam is related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem on HP laptop, on my machine idVendor 03f0 and idProduct 0c51 is Wireless Wide Area Network (WWAN): https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c04221330

I was able to disable it in: BIOS/UEFI -> Advanced -> Built-In Device Options -> Mobile Nerwork Device (WWAN)

After that dmesg spam stopped and other USB devices started to work without issues (previously I've had to plug-in USB device before I've booted HP laptop).

Comment: Same here: Linux Mint 20.3 XFCE and laptop HP EliteBook 820 G4, same WWLAN inside and same clutter when the following command is issued: $ tail -n 0 -f /var/log/syslog When I disabled that WWAN in BIOS everything started to behave normal. The funniest thing here is that that WIFI is working ;-)

Comment: @Rich No problem here with your comment but keep in mind that Linux Mint is not officially supported on Ask Ubuntu.